# Refactor method to use generics

Tags: java, generics

At first I write:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> getDataList() {
    ArrayList<Integer> dataList = new ArrayList<>(LEN);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        dataList.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(dataList);
    return dataList;
}
```

Later I decide to use generic:

```
private <E> ArrayList<E> getDataList() {
    ArrayList<E> dataList = new ArrayList<>(LEN);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        dataList.add(/* a procedure that generates E instance from index i*/);
    Collections.shuffle(dataList);
    return dataList;
}
```

Static methods in interface are not override-able, so can't call static method on E to generate instance.

How to refactor this to use generics? Thanks.

Comment: You could pass a function or supplier as an argument into your method to supply the elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to supply something that does the creation as a method parameter:

```
private <E> ArrayList<E> getDataList(IntFunction<? extends E> fn) {
```

Then:

```
dataList.add(fn.apply(i));
```

And invoke like:

```
List<Integer> integerList = getDataList(Integer::valueOf); // Same output as non-generic code.
List<String> stringList = getDataList(i -> "Item " + i);
```